# Is it possible to add a third monitor via ZoneScreen?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a dual-monitor setup that I’d like to add a third monitor to. I’m trying to use ZoneScreen and another computer to do this. When I run ZoneScreen it only gives me the option to send the video from one of the two already existing displays to the other computer. How can I get it to create and send a third display?

Answer (score 1):

The video driver makes the third display that you can choose.  ie; Display1, Display2, Display3 etc.  On Windows 7 there are some problems so you need to see the zonescreen website for instructions.  If you put Windows 7 in test mode for drivers, it seems to work fine.